# Reviewing "Not An Answer" flags

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

Since I recently reached 10k, I've been exploring the new found powers that I can use to help keep things tidy on StackOverflow.

One challenging list I noticed was over 100 "Not An Answer" flags. While some of these are obvious, and I can clearly confirm them, (should be an edit, etc) there many which I don't have the patience to figure them out. Perhaps this could be remedied if I had some tips from the pros...

What does one normally look for to know whether to confirm or disagree with (or skip :-o) "Not An Answer" flags?

And specifically, How would one handle this example, which is marked as Not An Answer, and what would be the reasoning behind your decision?

And also, I'm only 1% competent with C++, so I can't really judge it from a technical point of view. This is the case for many of these "Not An Answer"s

[Link To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481477/c-construct-derived-object-via-base-class-interface/19579368#19579368)

Quoted Answer: top answer with only +2 votes, 3,100 rep user

> You may be laboring under the misapprehension that it's possible in
>   C++ to write
>
> ```
> class ClownCar {
>     unsigned int x;
>     ClownCar inner_car;
> };
> ```
>
> But this is impossible! What would `sizeof(ClownCar)` be? It would
>   have to be at least `sizeof x + sizeof inner_car`; i.e.,
>   `sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(ClownCar)`; i.e., at least four bytes
>   bigger than itself.
>
> So, a class can't contain an instance of its own class. Inheritance,
>   virtual or otherwise, is irrelevant here. So what do we do? We use
>   pointers!
>
> ```
> class ClownCar {
>     unsigned int x;
>     ClownCar *inner_car;
> public:
>     ClownCar() : x(0), inner_car(nullptr) {}
>     ClownCar(unsigned int x, ClownCar *previous) : x(x), inner_car(previous) {}
>
>     ClownCar *getNext(unsigned int x) {
>         return new ClownCar(x, this);
>     }
> };
>
> int main() {
>     ClownCar inmost_car;
>     ClownCar *car1 = inmost_car.getNext(42);
>     ClownCar *car2 = car1.getNext(43);
>     // ...
>     delete car2;
>     delete car1;
>     // of course we don't delete inmost_car, since it lives on the stack
> }
> ```
>
> Of course this isn't very C++ish. We probably want to get rid of all
>   these `*`s, and also make it so that each car "takes ownership" of its
>   inner car (and takes responsibility for deleting it, too). We can do
>   this using the Standard Library's `std::unique_ptr` to represent this
>   concept of "ownership" (see also
>   [How do I pass a unique_ptr argument to a constructor or a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114276/how-do-i-pass-a-unique-ptr-argument-to-a-constructor-or-a-function))...
>   but really, all we've got here is a singly-linked list of `ClownCar`s,
>   and that's something that the STL gives us for free:
>
> ```
> struct ClownCar { unsigned int x; };
> typedef std::list<ClownCar> ClownCarList;  // ta-da!
> ```
>
> So I think the real question is, what are you trying to accomplish?

Quoted Question: -6 votes, 56 rep user, 100 rep bounty from author, ending in 10 hours

> I have a template class which is constructed by taking two arguments,
>   an integer and a previous instance of that class. I want to be able to
>   store instances of those classes in containers, which is why I have it
>   inheriting from a base class (please ignore the non-smart pointers):
>
> ```
> class base {
>   virtual base* getNext(unsigned x) = 0;
> };
>
> template <class D>
> class derived :
>   public base {
>
>   /* no memory allocation here, simply changes the data in next */
>   void construct_impl(unsigned x, const derived<D>& previous, derived<D>& next); 
>
>
>   derived();          /* default constructor */
>
>   derived(unsigned x, const derived<D>& previous) { /* construct from previous object */
>     allocate_memory_for_this();
>     construct_impl(x, previous, *this);
>   }
>
>   base* getNext(unsigned x) {
>     return new derived(x, *this);
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> Now I would like to create a function in the `base` class which will
>   construct an object of `derived<D>` in the same way as
>   `construct_impl` does, ie without allocating memory anew. I was
>   thinking something like this
>
> ```
> class base {
>   virtual base* getNext(unsigned x) = 0;
>   virtual void  getNext_noalloc(unsigned x, base* already_allocated_derived_object) = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> which will be overriden in the derived class like this
>
> ```
> void getNext_noalloc(unsigned x, base* already_allocated_derived_object) {
>      construct_impl(x, *this, *already_allocated_derived_object);    
> }
> ```
>
> which unfortunately does not compile since there is no conversion from
>   `base*` to `derived<D>*` (unless I use a static_cast). Is there any
>   way to achieve what I need? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an answer.  The flag is invalid.

"Not an Answer" flags should be used for things like:

- I have this same problem.  Has anyone found a solution?
- @someone: Your answer is correct, but...
- I have a new question.  How do I...
- +1 would vote again.

Technical knowledge is not required to review "Not an Answer" flags, nor is technical accuracy required in order for it to still be an answer.  If it looks like an answer, it probably is.